# Eloquent Javascript anchestry DNA script

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am reading Eloquent Javascript and I can not understand this script.How this work under hood?
where values comes from to fromMother and fromFather.
I searched about this in stackoverflow , I find but it did not help me understand this script

[Anchestry array](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/ancestry.js)

and scripts:

```
byName={};
    function reduceAncestors(person, f, defaultValue) {
      function valueFor(person) {
        if (person == null)
          return defaultValue;
        else

          return f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]),
                           valueFor(byName[person.father]));
      }
      return valueFor(person);
    }

    function forEach (array,action) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            action(array[i]);
        }
    }


    forEach(ANCESTRY_FILE,function (person) {
        byName[person.name]=person;
    })


    function sharedDNA(person, fromMother, fromFather) {
      if (person.name == "Pauwels van Haverbeke")
        return 1;
      else

        return (fromMother + fromFather) / 2;
    }
    var ph = byName["Philibert Haverbeke"];
    console.log(reduceAncestors(ph, sharedDNA, 0) / 4);
```

Comment: If you really want to know what happens where I would use a mixture between `debugger;` and `console.log()` statements as well as run through it step by step in debug mode in the browser console. - Might be a good idea to just use  single record in the source though, it is less confusing when debugging.

Comment: This code contains a bunch of function definitions. For example `sharedDNA` is defined as a function that takes 3 parameters: `person`, `fromMother`, `fromFather`. It is up to the code that calls this function to determine the values of the parameters and pass them to the function. Is this the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, running the code in a debugger will be the best way to understand it. However, here's a basic explanation:

`fromMother` and `fromFather` are arguments of the `sharedDNA` function. The `sharedDNA` function is passed as an argument to the `reduceAncestors` function in the last line of the script:

```
console.log(reduceAncestors(ph, sharedDNA, 0) / 4);
```

Inside the `reduceAncestors` function, `sharedDNA` is referred to as `f`. It is called on this line:

```
return f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]),
                           valueFor(byName[person.father]));
```

So, ultimately, the values of `fromMother` and `fromFather` are populated by the values returned by the two calls to the `valueFor` function in the line above.